# Spring how to set datasource in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-boot

I'm just learning Spring and I've been struggling for the past couple of days on how to configure the Spring JdbcTemplate to use my PostgreSQL database. I don't know how to do this. I keep reading the documentation, (such as http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)  but it seems like I'm going around in circles.

From the errors thrown it seems that it can't instantiate the RelationalDatabase Class that I wrote as a bean. I'm not sure what it would take to instantiate the class properly.

How do I move from something like the guides (Like https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) which totally work to a more complex solution?

**Relational Database Class**

```
@Repository
public class RelationalDatabase 
{

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public RelationalDatabase(){}


    public RelationalDatabase(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate)
    {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }


    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

**\src\main\resources\application-dev.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.56.102:5432/scibase
spring.datasource.type=org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource 
spring.datasource.username=lemon
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.max-active=100
spring.datasource.name=lime
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Drive
```

**Stack Trace (Summary)**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'relationalDatabase': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   com.scientifi.papers.db.relational.RelationalDatabase.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource);
>
> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
>
> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
>   Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type
>   NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on
>   the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "dev    "
>   are currently active).

Thanks!

Comment: How did you run the spring boot application? did you run with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev VM argument?

Comment: Have you added the PostgreSQL JAR to the pom/classpath?

Answer (score 3):

Did you forget the "r" in Driver? (*Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE*)

```
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

instead of

```
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Drive
```

Comment: I did forget that "r" but it was not it. I gave up Spring entirely. I went to the Spark micro-framework, which has actually been a lot easier. I have control over my code this way, and I've been importing libraries from Spring anyway, so I feel like I don't actually lose much.

Answer (score 0):

I Got the same Exception when i was testing my Spring Boot Application from Junit.

I resolved it using the @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class) above the Junit Test class. The Spring Boot application was not getting initialized properly